# MySQL Replication using GTID

Tags: mysql, replication

I want to create MySQL replication using GTID.

According to [MySQL Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-gtids-howto.html) I need the following settings in my.cnf (for the master)

```
server-id       = 1
log_bin         = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
gtid_mode = ON
log-slave-updates
enforce-gtid-consistency
```

I have also seen [this guide](https://www.looklinux.com/how-to-setup-gtid-replication-in-mysql-5-6/), which suggests the following settings in my.cnf (for master):

```
log-bin = mysql-bin
server-id = 1
relay-log = relay-log-slave
gtid-mode =ON
enforce-gtid-consistency
binlog_format = MIXED
log_slave_updates
```

Questions:

1. I have noticed that underscore and dash are being used loosely in the documents, for example when I installed MySQL on my computer, the variable name is `log_bin` but in MySQL manual they are using `log-bin`. Are _ and - interchangeable?
2. In the second tutorial that I have linked they are setting these two values in addition to setting values from MySQL manual: `relay-log = relay-log-slave` and `relay-log = relay-log-slave`. What are these two settings? And do I need them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_` and `-` are interchangeable in configuration files, however as SQL system variables only `_` is supported.

[relay-log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_relay-log) is a variable. `relay-log-slave` is just a value string.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry, this is a new question: In the tutorial, they are using `binlog_format = MIXED` for master and `binlog_format = ROW` on slave. Do you know what this means?

Comment: The thing about blogs and unofficial howtos/"tutorials" is they achieve one person's requirement a full communication of the requirements/understanding. The question you need to ask is why there is a replication log of the slave. The two main reasons are PITR (point in time recovery), or if there was another slave. On binlog_formats - [read this official manual comparison](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-sbr-rbr.html). Read the official documents, they are more correct and actually explain things. They are longer, but you'll make up for it with less failures.